# select sqlite item to variable

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite

I started with sqllite. I need some help with my code. Can I return a sqlite to a variable. I tried allmost everything.

I have this code

```
var db = window.openDatabase("localklussen", "1.0", "Local Klussenblok", 1000000);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS urls (id unique, url)');
});

function insertdata (serverurl) {
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO urls (id, url) VALUES (3, ?)', [serverurl]);
});
}
function selectdata(cb){
    db.transaction(function (tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM urls WHERE id = 1', [], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.item(0).url;
            cb.call(this, len);
        });
    });
}
```

I can't return the item to a variable like this:

```
$("#geturl").click(function(){
  console.log(selectdata());

  });
```

Is there a way to do this. The Item needs to go to a variable

Comment: aren't you supposed to pass something to your method?

Comment: You're logging the return value of `selectdata()`, which doesn't return anything. You're calling the `cb` callback function *from* `selectdata()`, but never passing a callback function *to* it, so `cb.call(this, len)` is basically `undefined.call(this, len)`.